# Django forms not saving to DB

Tags: python, django

I'm writing an app that has an HTML page which must be capable of saving data into 2 models. I've created two separate forms and referenced them in the view, however the information is not saving into the DB.

Here are the views.py

```
def nuevoingreso(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        formingreso = NuevoIngreso(request.POST)
        formprodingreso = NuevoProdIngreso(request.POST)
        if formingreso.is_valid():
            ingreso = formingreso.save(commit=False)
            ingreso.idUser = request.user
            ingreso.Condominio = get_object_or_404(Condominios, idCondominio=request.session["idCondominio"])
            ingreso.save()
            ingresoprod = formprodingreso.save()
            for i in range(5):
                if ProductosIngresos.SubtotalP != "" and ProductosIngresos.IvaP != "" and ProductosIngresos.TotalP != "":
                    ingresoprod.ProductosIngresos(Concepto=request.POST.get("Concepto"+str(i), ""), SubtotalP=request.POST.get("SubtotalP"+str(i), ""), IvaP=request.POST.get("IvaP"+str(i), ""), TotalP=request.POST.get("TotalP"+str(i), ""))
            ingresoprod.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/propiedades/")
        else:
            return render(request, "immovelc/nuevoingreso.html",
                          {"formingreso": formingreso, "formprodingreso": formprodingreso})
    propiedadesing = PropiedadesCond.objects.all()
    context = ({"propiedadesing": propiedadesing})
    return render(request, "immovelc/nuevoingreso.html", context)
```

forms.py

```
class NuevoIngreso(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Ingresos
        fields = ["Numero", "Persona", "Fecha", "Observaciones", "Cobrado", "Subtotal", "Iva", "Total"]
        def clean(self):
            Numero = self.cleaned_data["Numero"]
            Persona = self.cleaned_data["Persona"]
            Fecha = self.cleaned_data["Fecha"]
            if not Numero:
                raise forms.ValidationError("El campo de numero es obligatorio")
            if not Persona:
                raise forms.ValidationError("El campo de cliente es obligatorio")
            if not Fecha:
                raise forms.ValidationError("El campo de fecha es obligatorio")

class NuevoProdIngreso(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductosIngresos
        fields = ["Concepto", "SubtotalP", "IvaP", "TotalP"]
```

models.py

```
class Ingresos(models.Model):
    idIngreso = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, null=False, max_length=15)
    idCondominio = models.ForeignKey(Condominios)
    idUser = models.ForeignKey(User)
    Numero = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Persona = models.CharField(max_length=250, default="Ninguno")
    Cobrado = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=0)
    Observaciones = models.TextField(default="Ninguna")
    Fecha = models.DateField()
    Subtotal = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Iva = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Total = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.idIngreso)

class ProductosIngresos(models.Model):
    idProductoIngreso = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, null=False, max_length=15)
    idIngreso = models.ForeignKey(Ingresos)
    Concepto = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    SubtotalP = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    IvaP = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    TotalP = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.idProductoIngreso)
```

Thanks!

Comment: At least, your `clean()` method should be defined on a `ModelForm`, not inside `Meta`.

Comment: There might errors in submitted form, raised by `form.is_valid()`.

Answer (score 1):

No offence, but this code is far from being correct.

Besides you've got many errors that you might want to remove.

### Errors:

- `formprodingreso.is_valid()` is never called
- inside `for i in range(5)` you use a class as if it was an instance (`ProductosIngresos.SubtotalP`)
- `clean` method in form has to be outside the Meta block

I believe what you want inside the loop is:

```
producto_ingreso = ProductosIngresos()
producto_ingreso.idIngreso = ingreso # better change to producto_ingreso.ingreso
producto_ingreso.Concepto=request.POST.get("Concepto"+str(i), "") # producto_ingreso.concepto
producto_ingreso.SubtotalP=request.POST.get("SubtotalP"+str(i), "") # producto_ingreso.subtotal_p
producto_ingreso.IvaP=request.POST.get("IvaP"+str(i), "")
producto_ingreso.TotalP=request.POST.get("TotalP"+str(i), ""))
producto_ingreso.save()
```

To make it cleaner, you can make this king of logic overridding the save() method of ModelForm. Or use inline [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets).

### Confusion:

- Model FKs are objects in Django, not integers. Better name them like condominio instead of `idCondominio`
- Decimal columns (subtotal, iva, total) should be declared as deciaml i.e. `models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)`
- clean method is intended for cross field validation (more than one field). Only one field should be validated by `clean_numero` f.e.

### Over complication:

- models have ID/PK by default, no need to explicit them (referenced as `self.id` or `self.pk`)

  - model `unicode` function is not giving any info
  - clean and ValidationError are superflous: modelform checks if attributes are requiered automatically

### Convention errors:

- attributes are always written_in_lowercase (SubtotalP -> subtotal_p)

I would seriously try to fix all of those if you dont want the developers maintaining your code hate you and make some voodoo on you.